# Print job owner info?

Tags: windows-7, networking, printing, printer, network-printer

Print queue shows `HomeGroupUser$` as owner instead of network computer name or user name of the said network computer.

[image: Print Job sent directly and by network computer]

I'm looking to pause print jobs using the computer name; and then manually resume them using some script. **Note:** all computers are running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the default HomeGroup on Windows Network. This feature makes it easier to share printers and folders without having the users to enter their credentials. If you want to identify the Computer or User, you will need to setup a regular Workgroup Environment or Install a Domain controller.